# Memory Leak making images disappear

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, .net-4.0

First a little backgroud to the problem: We have an old Document Viewer that was created in WPF using NET 4.0 (we actually never updated, so still in 4.0) and a lot of developers actully worked on it, so it became kind of a mess. And one of the biggest problems was when we had images on the document, they were always taking a lot of memory [`OutOfMemoryException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.outofmemoryexception?view=netframework-4.0) and causing a lot of troubles when we wanted for example, to export the document to PDF, Word, etc.

I actually found a way to make the memory more stable by taking out the [`BitmapImage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage?view=netframework-4.0) which for some reason, was making the memory go from 200mb to 700mb most of the times during the export process.

This is the method being called to build the image:

```
public Image BuildImage(string path, double left, double top, double right, double bottom, double scaleWidth, double scaleHeight)
{
    Image _tempImage = new Image();
    try
    {
        _tempImage.Source = (new ImageSourceConverter()).ConvertFromString("file://" + path) as ImageSource;
        _tempImage.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        _tempImage.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        _tempImage.SetValue(FixedPage.LeftProperty, left * scaleWidth);
        _tempImage.SetValue(FixedPage.BottomProperty, bottom * scaleHeight);
        _tempImage.Width = (right - left) * scaleWidth;
        _tempImage.Height = (top - bottom) * scaleHeight;
        _tempImage.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        MessageBox.Show("Erro ao carregar imagem (1): " + e.Message);
        return null;
    }

    return _tempImage;
}
```

And here is a comparative of how the memory was after executing the 1º, 2º, 3º and 4º export
[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysYmj.png)]

Basically I have to find a way to "clear all the memory" after every export that happens, so in this way I would probably be able to prevent making the images disappear when I receive the `OutOfMemoryException`

This is actully the first time I'm working on C#, so maybe there's better ways to work with images outside the way I'm doing at the moment.

Comment: Have you tried creating a frozen BitmapImage or BitmapFrame from a FileStream instead of an Uri?

Comment: @Clemens Yes, when I started working on this project I was using a FileStream, but it was a long time ago and I made a lot of changes since that. I think I will give it a try later.

Comment: Also make sure to freeze the BitmapSource. Call Freeze() on a BitmapImage or use BitmapFrame.Create().

Comment: Well if there's a leak, then whatever is taking the return value of this function is, ostensibly, not releasing its references.  I would not expect to find the link within this function.

Comment: Are you actually disosing all those images?

Comment: @Evk There is no IDisposable involved.

Comment: @Clemens but Image (_tempImage) is disposable?

Comment: @Evk No, it's not. It is not a System.Drawing.Image.